# The created toolbar does not display properly on Android devices

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started learning Android development. I followed the [training document](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/appbar/setting-up) operation and tried to create a toolbar, but the result was inconsistent with the document when running in AVD.I hope someone can tell me how to achieve the effect in the training document, thank you

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            true
        }

        R.id.action_favorite -> {
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            true
        }

        else -> {
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

}
```

**menu/style.xml**

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/style"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
enter code here`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/style"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the effect on AVD: [Android virtual device display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcoQw.png)
but in Android Studio layout editor
it can display the effect I want:[Android Studio layout editor display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RKZD.png)

Comment: Maaaaaan, please edit your post, so we can read it, I tried to edit it, but you have too many problems.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the layout when I posted the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't inflated menu, so Activity doesn't know what to show:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.[id of your menu], menu)
    return true
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu)